# XML Serialization and Inherited Types

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, serialization, xml-serialization

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454/enforce-attribute-decoration-of-classesmethods) I have been working on getting my object model to serialize to XML. But I have now run into a problem (quelle surprise!).

The problem I have is that I have a collection, which is of a abstract base class type, which is populated by the concrete derived types.

I thought it would be fine to just add the XML attributes to all of the classes involved and everything would be peachy. Sadly, thats not the case!

So I have done some digging on Google and I now understand *why* it's not working. In that **the `XmlSerializer` is in fact doing some clever reflection in order to serialize objects to/from XML, and since its based on the abstract type, it cannot figure out what the hell it's talking to**. Fine.

I did come across [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xmlserializerforunknown.aspx) on CodeProject, which looks like it may well help a lot (yet to read/consume fully), but I thought I would like to bring this problem to the StackOverflow table too, to see if you have any neat hacks/tricks in order to get this up and running in the quickest/lightest way possible.

One thing I should also add is that I **DO NOT** want to go down the `XmlInclude` route. There is simply too much coupling with it, and this area of the system is under heavy development, so the it would be a real maintenance headache!

Comment: It would be helpful to see some relevant code snippets extracted from the classes you are trying to serialize.

Comment: Mate: I reopened because I feel other people could find this useful, but feel free to close if you disagree

Comment: Bit confused by this, since there has been nothing on this thread for so long?

Comment: There's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737666/xml-serialization-problem-deserializing-an-abstract-property

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Problem Solved!

OK, so I finally got there (admittedly with a **lot** of help from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xmlserializerforunknown.aspx)!).

So summarise:

#### Goals:

- I didn't want to go down the *XmlInclude* route due to the maintenence headache.
- Once a solution was found, I wanted it to be quick to implement in other applications.
- Collections of Abstract types may be used, as well as individual abstract properties.
- I didn't really want to bother with having to do "special" things in the concrete classes.

#### Identified Issues/Points to Note:

- *XmlSerializer* does some pretty cool reflection, but it is *very* limited when it comes to abstract types (i.e. it will only work with instances of the abstract type itself, not subclasses).
- The Xml attribute decorators define how the XmlSerializer treats the properties its finds. The physical type can also be specified, but this creates a **tight coupling** between the class and the serializer (not good).
- We can implement our own XmlSerializer by creating a class that implements *IXmlSerializable* .

### The Solution

I created a generic class, in which you specify the generic type as the abstract type you will be working with. This gives the class the ability to "translate" between the abstract type and the concrete type since we can hard-code the casting (i.e. we can get more info than the XmlSerializer can).

I then implemented the *IXmlSerializable* interface, this is pretty straight forward, but when serializing we need to ensure we write the type of the concrete class to the XML, so we can cast it back when de-serializing. It is also important to note it must be **fully qualified** as the assemblies that the two classes are in are likely to differ. There is of course a little type checking and stuff that needs to happen here.

Since the XmlSerializer cannot cast, we need to provide the code to do that, so the implicit operator is then overloaded (I never even knew you could do this!).

The code for the AbstractXmlSerializer is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Utility.Xml
{
    public class AbstractXmlSerializer<AbstractType> : IXmlSerializable
    {
        // Override the Implicit Conversions Since the XmlSerializer
        // Casts to/from the required types implicitly.
        public static implicit operator AbstractType(AbstractXmlSerializer<AbstractType> o)
        {
            return o.Data;
        }

        public static implicit operator AbstractXmlSerializer<AbstractType>(AbstractType o)
        {
            return o == null ? null : new AbstractXmlSerializer<AbstractType>(o);
        }

        private AbstractType _data;
        /// <summary>
        /// [Concrete] Data to be stored/is stored as XML.
        /// </summary>
        public AbstractType Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set { _data = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// **DO NOT USE** This is only added to enable XML Serialization.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>DO NOT USE THIS CONSTRUCTOR</remarks>
        public AbstractXmlSerializer()
        {
            // Default Ctor (Required for Xml Serialization - DO NOT USE)
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialises the Serializer to work with the given data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">Concrete Object of the AbstractType Specified.</param>
        public AbstractXmlSerializer(AbstractType data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        #region IXmlSerializable Members

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null; // this is fine as schema is unknown.
        }

        public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {
            // Cast the Data back from the Abstract Type.
            string typeAttrib = reader.GetAttribute("type");

            // Ensure the Type was Specified
            if (typeAttrib == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Unable to Read Xml Data for Abstract Type '" + typeof(AbstractType).Name +
                    "' because no 'type' attribute was specified in the XML.");

            Type type = Type.GetType(typeAttrib);

            // Check the Type is Found.
            if (type == null)
                throw new InvalidCastException("Unable to Read Xml Data for Abstract Type '" + typeof(AbstractType).Name +
                    "' because the type specified in the XML was not found.");

            // Check the Type is a Subclass of the AbstractType.
            if (!type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractType)))
                throw new InvalidCastException("Unable to Read Xml Data for Abstract Type '" + typeof(AbstractType).Name +
                    "' because the Type specified in the XML differs ('" + type.Name + "').");

            // Read the Data, Deserializing based on the (now known) concrete type.
            reader.ReadStartElement();
            this.Data = (AbstractType)new
                XmlSerializer(type).Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }

        public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {
            // Write the Type Name to the XML Element as an Attrib and Serialize
            Type type = _data.GetType();

            // BugFix: Assembly must be FQN since Types can/are external to current.
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
            new XmlSerializer(type).Serialize(writer, _data);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

So, from there, how do we tell the XmlSerializer to work with our serializer rather than the default? We must pass our type within the Xml attributes type property, for example:

```
[XmlRoot("ClassWithAbstractCollection")]
public class ClassWithAbstractCollection
{
    private List<AbstractType> _list;
    [XmlArray("ListItems")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ListItem", Type = typeof(AbstractXmlSerializer<AbstractType>))]
    public List<AbstractType> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set { _list = value; }
    }

    private AbstractType _prop;
    [XmlElement("MyProperty", Type=typeof(AbstractXmlSerializer<AbstractType>))]
    public AbstractType MyProperty
    {
        get { return _prop; }
        set { _prop = value; }
    }

    public ClassWithAbstractCollection()
    {
        _list = new List<AbstractType>();
    }
}
```

Here you can see, we have a collection and a single property being exposed, and all we need to do is add the *type* named parameter to the Xml declaration, easy! :D

**NOTE: If you use this code, I would really appreciate a shout-out. It will also help drive more people to the community :)**

Now, but unsure as to what to do with answers here since they all had their pro's and con's. I'll upmod those that I feel were useful (no offence to those that weren't) and close this off once I have the rep :)

Interesting problem and good fun to solve! :)

Comment: I ran into this problem myself some time ago. Personally, I ended up abandoning XmlSerializer and using the IXmlSerializable interface directly, since all my classes needed to implement it anyway. Otherwise, the solutions are quite similar. Good write-up though :)

Comment: We use XML_ properties where we convert the list to Arrays :)

Comment: why is it necessary to declare the default constructor, if you're not allowed to use it ?

Comment: Because a parameterless constructor is needed in order to dynamically instantiate the class.

Comment: Hello! I've been looking for a solution like this for quite some time now. I think it's brilliant! Allthough im not able to figure out how to use it, would you mind to give an example?
Are you serializing your class or the list, containing your objects?

Comment: Nice code. Note that the parameterless contructor could be declared `private` or `protected` to enforce that it not be available to other classes.

Comment: I'm not able to make your class work in my project, but it seems to be exactly what I need! I would definitely like to see an example of how you call the Serialize method.

Comment: @Daniel / @Fueled - Unfortunately I jumped the .NET ship a few months ago and I currently don't have a working Windows build to put some code together for you. The key bit is to ensure that you are setting the `Type` in the XML attribs that decorate your properties. Ensure they are also generics of the "Abstract Type". The serialiser will pick up the rest.

Comment: @tcovo - read the code, the default paramless constructor HAS to be public - it's a requirement from the framework.

Comment: @RobCooper - Sorry, I guess my earlier comment was a bit vague. Since .NET 2.0 (ca. 2006), the parameterless constructor can be `private` or `protected` for the purpose of serialization by XmlSerializer. [Reference (last comment)](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/254694/)

Comment: After following the steps linked in the OP (Article by Hewitt), and using the fqn as done here, I had one problem left: It failed on grand children (double inherited). Adding another implicit operator solved it.

Comment: Great solution.  A potential "gotcha" if you're not paying attention (like me), the Xml node that represents the AbstractXmlSerializer cannot be the same node representing your concrete type.  E.g. reading <MyNode Type="MyClass" MyProp="abc"> won't work, but reading <MyNode Type="MyClass"><MyClass MyProp="abc"> will.  It's obvious after the fact, but my original source XML had those nodes merged.

Comment: Great Solution ... but I have a question.  If we are not dealing with legacy code would it make sense to avoid the "abstract" class hierarchy all together?  My concern is IXmlSerializable is the LEAST efficient choice for serialization (all be it most flexible).  I would assume it preferable to focus on more efficient serializers where possible.  If IXmlSerializable is the only option, or you expect a lot of communication to external (non-.net) systems & devices ... then this can be a great solution for helping maintain class hierarchies.

Comment: Excellent solution! I just replaced type.AssemblyQualifiedName in the WriteXml method with type.Assembly.GetName().Name (same, but without version numbers) to avoid versioning issues...

Comment: Just noticed this fails if the collection is empty. Adding if(data != null) to the WriteXml method fixes that.

Comment: How can i debug the class AbstractXmlSerializer<AbstractType>?
I am getting an error on serializing.

`Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'MyType' to 'AbstractXmlSerializer<MyType>'`

Comment: I think i am doing this wrong in vb.net.
`public static implicit operator AbstractType(AbstractXmlSerializer<AbstractType> o)
        {
            return o.Data;
        }
`
    
How can i do this implicit Operator overload in vb.net

Comment: Ok, after some googeling around i found this SO Question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312549/is-there-a-way-to-define-an-implicit-conversion-operator-in-vb-net
Now the implementation seems to work

Comment: I have now an issue on reading the XML back to the base class.
The xml returns as typeAttrib 
 
`"SQL_Connector.FunctionSetupViewERP_PDM, SQL-Connector, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`

This is the correct full quallified name to my derrived type.
Also the assembly containing the type (SQL-Connector) is loaded into the current appdomain.
But in my GenericSerialize `Type.Gettype(typeAttrib)` returns NULL. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 9):

One thing to look at is the fact that in the XmlSerialiser constructor you can pass an array of types that the serialiser might be having difficulty resolving. I've had to use that quite a few times where a collection or complex set of datastructures needed to be serialised and those types lived in different assemblies etc.

[XmlSerialiser Constructor with extraTypes param](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx)

EDIT: I would add that this approach has the benefit over XmlInclude attributes etc that you can work out a way of discovering and compiling a list of your possible concrete types at runtime and stuff them in.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, but it is not easy as I was thinking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897818/xmlserializer-the-type-type-may-not-be-used-in-this-context

Comment: This is a very old post but for anyone looking into implementing this like we did, please note XmlSerializer's constructor with extraTypes param **does not cache** the assemblies it generates on the fly. This costs us weeks of debugging that memory leak. So if you are to use the extra types with the accepted answer's code, **cache the serializer**. This behavior is documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/886385

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, an extensible framework of POCOs will never serialize to XML reliably.  I say this because I can guarantee someone will come along, extend your class, and botch it up.

You should look into using XAML for serializing your object graphs.  It is designed to do this, whereas XML serialization isn't.

The Xaml serializer and deserializer handles generics without a problem, collections of base classes and interfaces as well (as long as the collections themselves implement `IList` or `IDictionary`).  There are some caveats, such as marking your read only collection properties with the `DesignerSerializationAttribute`, but reworking your code to handle these corner cases isn't that hard.

Comment: Link seems to be dead

Comment: Oh, well.  I'll nuke that bit.  Plenty of other resources out about the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick update on this, I have not forgotten!

Just doing some more research, looks like I am on to a winner, just need to get the code sorted.

So far, I have the following:

- The *XmlSeralizer* is basically a class that does some nifty reflection on the classes it is serializing. It determines the properties that are serialized based on the **Type**.
- The reason the problem occurs is because a type mismatch is occurring, it is expecting the *BaseType* but in fact receives the *DerivedType* .. While you may think that it would treat it polymorphically, it doesn't since it would involve a whole extra load of reflection and type-checking, which it is not designed to do.

This behaviour appears to be able to be overridden (code pending) by creating a proxy class to act as the go-between for the serializer. This will basically determine the type of the derived class and then serialize that as normal. This proxy class then will feed that XML back up the line to the main serializer..

Watch this space! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly a solution to your problem, but there is another problem, which somewhat undermines your intention to use "portable" XML format. Bad thing happens when you decide to change classes in the next version of your program and you need to support both formats of serialization -- the new one and the old one (because your clients still use thier old files/databases, or they connect to your server using old version of your product). But you can't use this serializator anymore, because you used

```
type.AssemblyQualifiedName
```

which looks like

```
TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass+NestedClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089
```

that is contains your assembly attributes and version...

Now if you try to change your assembly version, or you decide to sign it, this deserialization is not going to work...

Answer (score 1):

I've done things similar to this. What I normally do is make sure all the XML serialization attributes are on the concrete class, and just have the properties on that class call through to the base classes (where required) to retrieve information that will be de/serialized when the serializer calls on those properties. It's a bit more coding work, but it does work much better than attempting to force the serializer to just do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, using notation:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class MyClass {
    public abstract class MyAbstract {} 
    public class MyInherited : MyAbstract {} 
    [XmlArray(), XmlArrayItem(typeof(MyInherited))] 
    public MyAbstract[] Items {get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: This is great if you know your classes, it's the most elegant sollution. If you load new inherited classes from an external source then you can't use it unfortunately.