# XmlSerializer - There was an error reflecting type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, .net-2.0

Using C# .NET 2.0, I have a composite data class that does have the `[Serializable]` attribute on it.  I am creating an `XMLSerializer` class and passing that into the constructor:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataClass));
```

I am getting an exception saying:

> There was an error reflecting type.

Inside the data class there is another composite object.  Does this also need to have the `[Serializable]` attribute, or by having it on the top object, does it recursively apply it to all objects inside?

Answer (score 446, accepted):

Look at the inner exception that you are getting.  It will tell you which field/property it is having trouble serializing.

You can exclude fields/properties from xml serialization by decorating them with the [`[XmlIgnore]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute) attribute.

`XmlSerializer` does not use the [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute) attribute, so I doubt that is the problem.

Comment: My object had a Uri field, which caused this exception; the Uri class does not have a parameterless constructor. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Came across this with a google search - my particular issue was having a property in my "to be serialized" class as `IList` when it needed to be `List`.

Comment: How does one look at an "inner exception"?

Comment: @David: try{ ... }catch(Exception e){Exception ie = e.InnerException}

Comment: or add '@exception' to a watch

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me out. I initially looked at the inner exception, and just saw mentioning of the main class. But I realised I could drill down into the innerexceptions of the innrexceptions, and eventually, 5 levels down, I found the issue. I had classes that were conflicting. Thanks.

Comment: same as @LouisvanTonder, had to go down a few innerexceptions before I found which class was missing an empty constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Roland!  I never realized you could access that information.  Very useful.  To debug my issue, I printed out all the inner exceptions like this: try{...}catch(Exception e){/*print e.Message*/ for(Exception ie = e.InnerException; null != ie; ie = ie.InnerException){/*print ie.Message*/}}

Comment: @thehelix write yoda conditions you should not.

Comment: @thehelix I don't know if I would ever use your 'yoda' expression but I like to learn yet another way to do things, thanks. But do you really suggest to take the InnerException of an InnerException? Don't you really intend: `for(Exception TheExc = e; TheExc != null; TheExc = TheExc.InnerException){print TheExc.Message;}` ??

Comment: @Roland, I uncovered three inner exceptions by drilling into and printing all the nested InnerExceptions.  This revealed some interesting information that ultimately solved some issues I was having.  I like to debug with verbose logging, so this suits me.  :)  Yoda expressions are a habit I have because I've been burnt by assignment errors enough times over the years to not want to waste time tracking them down anymore.  It's automatic for me now, but I support either convention.  :)

Comment: @Roland, thanks alot on how to check the Inner exception! I had a similar exception, but it turned out that it was just because another class of mine was inaccessible due to its protection level XD..... All in all, this question really helped me out just by directing me to view its Inner exception. Turns out it was just missing a "public" in front of a class 9.9

Comment: I had one of my properties as IList, changed it to List and wallah!

Comment: for me it was that i had `[XmlArray]` and `[XmlArrayItem(typeof(Column))]` above a non list property

Comment: Going to innerexception --> innerexception --> innerexception  --> innerexception helped me go to the error point.

Answer (score 121):

Remember that serialized classes must have default (i.e. parameterless) constructors. If you have no constructor at all, that's fine; but if you have a constructor with a parameter, you'll need to add the default one too.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I hate that this is a runtime error with little explanation.

Comment: I keep on making this mistake over and over again. thanks for reminding me to use a parameterless constructor ^^

Comment: What if the serialized 'class' is a delegate?

Answer (score 29):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out that the serializer could not distinguish between 2 classes I had with the same name (one was a subclass of the other).  The inner exception looked like this:

'Types BaseNamespace.Class1' and 'BaseNamespace.SubNamespace.Class1' both use the XML type name, 'Class1', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

Where BaseNamespace.SubNamespace.Class1 is a subclass of BaseNamespace.Class1.

What I needed to do was add an attribute to one of the classes (I added to the base class):

```
[XmlType("BaseNamespace.Class1")]
```

Note: If you have more layers of classes you need to add an attribute to them as well.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, thank you, +1; I had a similar setting with several Processor* objects, each one with a Config inner class. The runtime was not able to distinguish between SomeNS.Processor1.Config and SomeNS.Processor2.Config.

Answer (score 8):

Most common reasons by me:

```
 - the object being serialized has no parameterless constructor
 - the object contains Dictionary
 - the object has some public Interface members
```

Answer (score 7):

Also be aware that `XmlSerializer` cannot serialize abstract properties.. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084/xml-serialization-and-inherited-types) (which I have added the solution code to)..

[XML Serialization and Inherited Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084/xml-serialization-and-inherited-types)

Answer (score 6):

I just got the same error and discovered that a property of type `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` was the problem. It appears that `IEnumerable` cannot be serialized directly.

Instead, one could use `List<SomeClass>`.

Answer (score 5):

All the objects in the serialization graph have to be serializable.

Since `XMLSerializer` is a blackbox, check these links if you want to debug further into the serialization process..

[Changing where XmlSerializer Outputs Temporary Assemblies](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=XmlSerializer)

[HOW TO: Debug into a .NET XmlSerializer Generated Assembly](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HOWTODebugIntoANETXmlSerializerGeneratedAssembly.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to handle specific attributes (i.e. Dictionary, or any class), you can implement the [IXmlSerialiable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28VS.80%29.aspx) interface, which will allow you more freedom *at the cost of more verbose coding*.

```
public class NetService : IXmlSerializable
{
    #region Data

        public string Identifier = String.Empty;

        public string Name = String.Empty;

        public IPAddress Address = IPAddress.None;
        public int Port = 7777;

    #endregion

    #region IXmlSerializable Implementation

        public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return (null); }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            // Attributes
            Identifier = reader[XML_IDENTIFIER];
            if (Int32.TryParse(reader[XML_NETWORK_PORT], out Port) == false)
            throw new XmlException("unable to parse the element " + typeof(NetService).Name + " (badly formatted parameter " + XML_NETWORK_PORT);
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(reader[XML_NETWORK_ADDR], out Address) == false)
            throw new XmlException("unable to parse the element " + typeof(NetService).Name + " (badly formatted parameter " + XML_NETWORK_ADDR);
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            // Attributes
            writer.WriteAttributeString(XML_IDENTIFIER, Identifier);
            writer.WriteAttributeString(XML_NETWORK_ADDR, Address.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString(XML_NETWORK_PORT, Port.ToString());
        }

        private const string XML_IDENTIFIER = "Id";

        private const string XML_NETWORK_ADDR = "Address";

        private const string XML_NETWORK_PORT = "Port";

    #endregion
}
```

There is an interesting [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164135.aspx), which show an elegant way to implements a sophisticated way to "extend" the XmlSerializer.

---

The article say:

> IXmlSerializable is covered in the official documentation, but the documentation states it's not intended for public use and provides no information beyond that. This indicates that the development team wanted to reserve the right to modify, disable, or even completely remove this extensibility hook down the road. However, as long as you're willing to accept this uncertainty and deal with possible changes in the future, there's no reason whatsoever you can't take advantage of it.

Because this, I suggest to implement you're own `IXmlSerializable` classes, in order to avoid too much complicated implementations.

...it could be straightforward to implements our custom `XmlSerializer` class using reflection.

Answer (score 4):

I've discovered that the Dictionary class in .Net 2.0 is not serializable using XML, but serializes well when binary serialization is used.

I found a work around [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I recently got this in a web reference partial class when adding a new property. The auto generated class was adding the following attributes.

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = XX)]
```

I needed to add a similar attribute with an order one higher than the last in the auto generated sequence and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I too thought that the Serializable attribute had to be on the object but unless I'm being a complete noob (I am in the middle of a late night coding session) the following works from the [SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Inner
{
    private string _AnotherStringProperty;
    public string AnotherStringProperty 
    { 
      get { return _AnotherStringProperty; } 
      set { _AnotherStringProperty = value; } 
    }
}

public class DataClass
{
    private string _StringProperty;
    public string StringProperty 
    { 
       get { return _StringProperty; } 
       set{ _StringProperty = value; } 
    }

    private Inner _InnerObject;
    public Inner InnerObject 
    { 
       get { return _InnerObject; } 
       set { _InnerObject = value; } 
    }
}

public class MyClass
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataClass));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\tmp\dataClass.xml");
            DataClass clazz = new DataClass();
            Inner inner = new Inner();
            inner.AnotherStringProperty = "Foo2";
            clazz.InnerObject = inner;
            clazz.StringProperty = "foo";
            serializer.Serialize(writer, clazz);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

I would imagine that the XmlSerializer is using reflection over the public properties.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime, this type of error is because you dont have constructur of class without argument

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation where the Order was the same for two elements in a row

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true, Order = 0, ElementName = "SeriousInjuryFlag")]
```

.... some code ...

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true, Order = 0, ElementName = "AccidentFlag")]
```

When I changed the code to increment the order by one for each new Property in the class, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when I created a property having a datatype - `Type`. On this, I was getting an error - There was an error reflecting type. I kept checking the 'InnerException' of every exception from the debug dock and got the specific field name (which was `Type`) in my case. The solution is as follows:

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you cannot serialize user interface controls and that any object you want to pass onto the clipboard must be serializable otherwise it cannot be passed across to other processes.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the `NetDataSerialiser` class to serialise 
my domain classes. [NetDataContractSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx).

The domain classes are shared between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("strFieldName", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
```

Or

```
[XmlIgnore]
string [] strFielsName {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case the object had a ReadOnlyCollection. A collection must implement Add method to be serializable.

Comment: This is not a proper answer to the question. There are other 15 answers already on this question. If you think your answer is better than the others you should provide more details about it. Providing some code & output snippets always help users. Before posting your answers consider reading -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different solution to all described here so far, so for any future civilisation here's mine!

I had declared a datatype of "time" as the original type was a `TimeSpan` and subsequently changed to a `String`:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="time", Order=3)]
```

however the actual type was a string

```
public string TimeProperty {
    get {
        return this.timePropertyField;
    }
    set {
        this.timePropertyField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeProperty");
    }
}
```

by removing the `DateType` property the `Xml` can be serialized

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
public string TimeProperty {
    get {
        return this.timePropertyField;
    }
    set {
        this.timePropertyField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeProperty");
    }
}
```