# XMLDeserialize, "There was an error reflecting type"

Tags: c#, reflection, xml-serialization, deserialization, ixmlserializable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XmlSerializer - There was an error reflecting type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573/xmlserializer-there-was-an-error-reflecting-type)

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(configType));
```

> There was an error reflecting type 'MyNameSpace.configType'.

I'll pare away at `configType` some more in the hope of finding the problem. Apart from removing ostensibly redundant attributes the only change I made to it after generating it from xsd.exe was replacing one of the generated classes with my own so I could better implement the serialization of optional elements.

Thanks for the hints to examine that innerException, it traced back to the class I made implement IXmlSerializable, which is now in its own file and presented below:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [Serializable(), XmlType(Namespace = "MyNameSpace")] //Naughty xsd.exe!
    public class OpOpts : IXmlSerializable
    {
        void defaultFlags()
        {
            Opt1 = true;
            Opt2 = true;
            Opt5 = false;
        }

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() { return (null); }
        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            defaultFlags();
            //            reader.Read();
            while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case "Opt1": Opt1 = reader.ReadElementContentAsBoolean();
                        break;
                    case "Opt2": Opt2 = reader.ReadElementContentAsBoolean();
                        break;
                    case "Opt5": Opt5 = reader.ReadElementContentAsBoolean();
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Invalid XML tag " + reader.Name + " found under OpOpts.");
                }
            }
        }
        enum OptionEnum
        {
            Opt1, Opt2, Opt5
        }
        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            OpOpts defOpts = new OpOpts();
            if (Opt1 != defOpts.Opt1) writer.WriteElementString("Opt1", Opt1.ToString());
            if (Opt2 != defOpts.Opt2) writer.WriteElementString("Opt2", Opt2.ToString());
            if (Opt5 != defOpts.Opt5) writer.WriteElementString("Opt5", Opt5.ToString());
        }

        public bool Opt1 { get; set; }
        public bool Opt2 { get; set; }
        public bool Opt5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

jdehaan wrote a nice article, [Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable/1629671#1629671). After reading his codeproject I found that the stuff that xsd.exe generated for my proto-class was breaking the class I extended to implement `IXMLSerializable`.

Specifically the attribute [XmlType(Namespace = "MyNameSpace")] causes the error "reflecting property". When I remove it I get a bit further, the containing class passes deserialization of everything else but cries "Invalid XML tag" when it comes to the member representing my class above.

Comment: Look at the inner exception, it should give you more information

Comment: Look at the inner exception, it should give you more information about what's wrong. The most common issue I see is that the type being (de)serialized is not public.