# How do I use classes in this C# script which saves and loads files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I put classes in this C# script which saves and loads files. I am currently in process of learning C#. I have to make a project for school with C# which loads and saves files with use of classes. I learned how to work with classes, but I am really getting confused when I have to make use of this in my script:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
        {
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(open.FileName));
            textBox1.Text = read.ReadToEnd();
            read.Dispose(); 
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

        if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(save.FileName));

            write.Write(textBox1.Text);
            write.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why bother? look at `System.File`. Specifically, `ReadAllText` and `WriteAllText` methods.

Comment: if you want to save/load classes as a file. you can look into the XMLReader. look into this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266536/8579225)

Comment: You *are* using classes in that code - `OpenFileDialog`, `StreamReader`, `File`. etc are all classes. Further all the code you include here must be inside a class of its own (I'm guessing it might be called `Form1`). But is the requirement that you must create new classes to load a file into a text box/save from a text box into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main point of your exercise is to separate responsabilities.

**Every class should accomplish one task only.**

According to this principle it is good practice to logically split your programs in three levels (UI, Business and Data layer).

There's a lot to discuss on this so i suggest you to have a look to **SOLID** principles and **3-Tier** level architectures

To help you I suggest you to change your code as follows (this example uses three levels but if you use two levels it is good enough and your teacher won't suspect you received a hint)

```
   // You User Interface, should use Business level classes (not data)
    class YourForm
    {
        private readonly YourService _myLogicService;

        public YourForm()
        {
            _myLogicService = new YourService(new YourFilePersistor());
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
            {
                textBox1.Text = _myLogicService.Read(open.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var toSave = textBox1.Text;

            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                _myLogicService.Write(save.FileName, toSave);
            }
        }
    }

    // Data Layer: this class has dependencies from file system 
    // (in future a database can be used but you will not change your business service, just implement the interface)
    public class YourFilePersistor : IPersistor
    {
        public string Read(string filePath)
        {
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath); // Or your code
        }

        public void Write(string filePath, string fileContent)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContent); // Or your code
        }
    }

    public interface IPersistor
    {
        string Read(string filePath);

        void Write(string filePath, string fileContent);
    }



    // Service is your "Business Level" for put your application logic on your domain data  
    // Business classes uses intefaces to abstract data layer and work without dependencies from components like database, remote apis and so on...
    public class YourService
    {
        private readonly IPersistor _repository;

        public YourService(IPersistor repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public string Read(string filePath)
        {
            var data = _repository.Read(filePath);

            return data;
        }

        public void Write(string filePath, string fileContent)
        {
            var data = fileContent;
            // here you could do some logic i.e. to validate your data  
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileContent))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Data is null");
            }
            // ---

            _repository.Write(filePath, data);
        }
    }
```