# .net 4.6 Methods in Serializable class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

I am new to serialization and am facing a problem. I have a serializable class, which MUST contain a method. But because of that method I am getting an error during initialization of serializer (when i comment the method, no errors are thrown).
The question - is there a way to mark method in the class so serializer would ignore it and work properly?

This is my serializable class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Key
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Kid")]
        public Guid Kid { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("CEK")]
        public string CEK { private get; set; }

        public string Foo()
        {...}
    }
```

I have a little modified it in terms of privacy of data, but it doesn't influence the topic.

Here is how I do the serialization:

```
        StringReader strReader = null;
            XmlSerializer serializer = null;
            XmlTextReader xmlReader = null;
            Object obj = null;
            try
            {
                strReader = new StringReader(xml);
                serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType,
                    new XmlRootAttribute
                    {
                        ElementName = "someNS",
                        Namespace = "url.to.some.namespace"
                    });
                xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(strReader);
                obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
         }
```

Error is thrown at this part:

```
serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType,
    new XmlRootAttribute
    {
        ElementName = "someNS",
        Namespace = "url.to.some.namespace"
    });
```

UPDATE:
Right, forgot about the error. It is the following:

> System.InvalidOperationException:'There was an error reflecting type
>   'MyProject.Objects.Key'.'

and inner exeptions:

> InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property
>   'Key'.
>   InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'MyProject.Objects.Key'.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the error is.

Comment: Please check [MCVE] guidance on providing code... Serializes generally ignore methods, so without actual error message or complete code to reproduce the error it is hard to guess what is wrong.

Comment: And `[Serializable]` is not needed unless you want to use `BinaryFormatter` for serialization.

Comment: Are there no inner exceptions within those? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60581/1945651) suggests that "There was an error reflecting type" errors have an inner exception indicating the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it :

```
[XmlElement("CEK")]
public string CEK { private get; set; }
```

This property caused exception; you can't make get a private method in serializable class.