# How to fix this error in Deserialization?

Tags: c#, deserialization

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in sCreator.exe
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'sCreator.Shape'.

Here's the code:

```
    public void Deseriaize(StreamReader file)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
        Shape s = (Shape)ser.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(s.title);
    }

    private void btn_OpenProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\pb8n0053\Documents\SerializationOverview.seal");
        Deseriaize(file);
    }
```

**Shape Class**

```
 [Serializable]
public class Shape
{
    //Properties
    public Draw draw;
    public String title;
    public float width { get; set; }
    public float height { get; set; }
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
    public static PointF center = new PointF(250f, 250f);
    public int strokeThickness { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public float userDefinedWidth { get; set; }
    public float userDefinedHeight { get; set; }
    public int userDefinedStroke { get; set; }
    public SizeF size;
    public PointF location;
    public float radius;
    public ShapeType type;
    public Status status;
    public enum ShapeType
    {
        rectangle, square, circle, ellipse, triangle, image
    }
    public enum Status
    {
        editing, start
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `Shape` class as well?

Comment: @RonBeyer added the class and it's properties

Comment: What is the `Draw` class?

Comment: @RonBeyer the class for my redrawing all shapes, and etc

Comment: That is probably not serializable, so either you need to mark it as non-serialized, or handle it with custom serialization.

Comment: I marked it. Now I get this error: **<string xmlns=''> was not expected.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `XmlSerializer` is being created with `typeof(string)` as the argument to the constructor. This means that that serializer is intended to convert XML to and from a `System.String`. If you want it to convert your XML to and from your `Shape` type, then initialize it using that instead:

```
public void Deseriaize(StreamReader file)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shape));
    Shape s = (Shape)ser.Deserialize(file);
    file.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(s.title);
}
```

Note that your serialization/deserialization cycle will probably fail or work incorrectly if you try to deserialize XML that was not created with `XmlSerializer` or if your `Shape` class does not properly implement `ISerializable`.

Comment: I get this error now: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: There was an error reflecting type 'sCreator.Shape'.**

Comment: @untargeted This means that there is a problem with your `Shape` class; it likely contains a member that `XmlSerializer` does not know how to handle. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573/xmlserializer-there-was-an-error-reflecting-type) and make sure your type has a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: @untargeted I can't be sure without seeing the inner exception, but the problem is likely either with that member of type `Draw`, which may not be serializable.

Comment: [PointF is serializable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/PointF.cs), same with [SizeF](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/SizeF.cs)

Comment: I marked 'draw' as non serializable. Now I get this error: <string xmlns=''> was not expected.

Comment: @untargeted Did you create the XML that you are trying to deserialize using an `XmlSerializer` with `typeof(Shape)` as its constructor argument?

Comment: As a string. If I serialize it as type of Shape. It would produce this error, **There was an error generating the XML document.** @laptou

Comment: Oh. I already fixed it. It was the serialization problem after all. thank to all of you.

Comment: @RonBeyer `SerializableAttribute` does not affect XML serialization; only binary serialization.