# XML Serialization on a custom data

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a XML file:

```
<Hand cards="C5,SQ,DQ,H8,C9,H7,S9,D5,DA,CJ,S6,HK,D4">
</Hand>
```

I define a class

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Hand")]
public class Hand
{
    [XmlAttribute("cards")]
    public List<string> Cards{get;set;}
}
```

How to deserialize a XML to object in this case? Hand object result must have Cards = {C5,SQ,DQ,H8,C9,H7,S9,D5,DA,CJ,S6,HK,D4}.

Comment: Heres an easy starting point for the basics on MSDN  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You will have to do a custom serialization. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1075860/24047.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot.

What you can do is to create a property which will do this conversion in its getter/setter

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<string> CardList { get; private set; }

[XmlAttribute("cards")]
public string Cards {
   get { return String.Join(",", CardList); }
   set { CardList = value.Split(",").ToList(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the help of `IXmlSerializable`. Read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx).

This way

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Hand")]
public class Hand : IXmlSerializable {
    [XmlAttribute("cards")]
    public List<string> Cards { get; set; }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        this.Cards = new List<string>(reader.GetAttribute("cards").Split(','));
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("cards", 
             string.Join(",", 
                this.Cards != null ? this.Cards : new List<string>()));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: FYI `[Serializable]` is not used by the XML Serializer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Right, that is used for Binary Serialization. It was there in OP's code.