# XML deserialization of weakly typed objects in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Sorry for a crappy title. Feel free to change it to a better one.

The problem is this: I have a need to read a set of XML files that look like this:

```
<rootElement>
   <header>
      <!-- some stuff here -->
   </header>
   <businessContent>
      <oneOfSeveralAllowedSubNodesHereLikeCustomer />
   <businessContent>
</rootElement>
```

I got `xsd.exe` to generate C# classes from a schema file I've got and it did it like that (simplified):

```
public class rootElement
{
   public header header {get;set;}
   public object businessContent {get;set;}
}
// other classes like header and classes for the values
// allowed within business content, say customer
```

Notice that the type of `businessContent` is `System.Object` which is fair enough. The schema says nothing explicitly about what can actually be put in there. But then I have an xml file which has a `customer` inside its `businessContent`. customer is defined in the xsd and the `xsd.exe` generated a class for it as well. I would expect an instance of this class to be created and put as my `businessContent` but when I read the XML:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rootElement));
var root = (rootElement)serializer.Deserialize(stream));
var customer = (customer)root.businessContent;
```

I get an exception, because the type of `root.businessContent` is `XmlNode[]` and not `customer`.

So how do I make the serializer to deserialize my object fully, that is with `customer` and not `XmlNode[]` inside?

Answer (score 1):

[Serializing and restoring an unknown class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590658/serializing-and-restoring-an-unknown-class)

```
var extraTypes = new[] { typeof(customer), typeof(otherAllowedSubnodeTypes) };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rootElement), extraTypes);
```

Comment: This ends up in exception complaining that the anonymous type customer can not be used here

Comment: Is this a compiler error or a runtime exception?  Can you give us the exact error message?  `customer` isn't an anonymous type, so I don't understand what you said.

Comment: it has 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]

Comment: The exception is System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot include anonymous type 'customer'.
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.IncludeType(Type type, RecursionLimiter limiter)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, Type[] extraTypes, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, Type[] extraTypes)