# Deserialize xml element to POCO base class

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

Following this link: [Deserialize xml into super class object with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292634/deserialize-xml-into-super-class-object-with-c-sharp)

I had implemented:

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xPlugins>
  <xPlugin>
    <Multiple>
      <Operator>
        <Add>
          <Operator>1</Operator>
          <Operator>2</Operator>
        </Add>        
      </Operator>
      <Operator>
        <Add>
          <Operator>3</Operator>
          <Operator>4</Operator>
        </Add>
      </Operator>
    </Multiple>
  </xPlugin>
</xPlugins>
```

classes

```
public abstract class Calculator
{
    public Calculator() { }

    public virtual int Calculate()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Operator : Calculator
{
    public int value { get; set; }

    public Operator() { }

    public Operator(string name)
    {
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class Add : Calculator
{
    public List<Calculator> calculators { get; set; }

    public Add() { }

    public Add(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {         
        List<int> value = new List<int>();

        foreach (Calculator calculator in calculators)
        {
            value.Add(calculator.Calculate());
        }

        return value.Sum();
    }
}

public class Minus : Calculator
{
    public List<Calculator> calculators { get; set; }

    public Minus() { }

    public Minus(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        int value = calculators[0].Calculate();

        for (int i = 1; i < calculators.Count; i++)
        {
            value -= calculators[i].Calculate();
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public class divide: Calculator
{
    public List<Calculator> calculators { get; set; }

    public Divide() { }

    public Divide(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        int value = calculators[0].Calculate();

        for (int i = 1; i < calculators.Count; i++)
        {
            value /= calculators[i].Calculate();
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public class Multiple : Calculator
{
    public List<Calculator> calculators { get; set; }

    public Multiple() { }

    public Multiple(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        int value = calculators[0].Calculate();

        for (int i = 1; i < calculators.Count; i++)
        {
            value *= calculators[i].Calculate();
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public class xPlugin
{        
    public Calculator calculator { get; set; }
}

public class xPlugins
{
    [XmlElement("xPlugin", typeof(xPlugin))]
    public xPlugin[] Plugin { get; set; }
}
```

Xml Serializer definition:

```
public static void getObject(ref xPlugins plugins)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Type> type = new List<Type>();
            type.Add(typeof(Add));
            type.Add(typeof(Minus));
            type.Add(typeof(Multiple));
            type.Add(typeof(Subtract));
            type.Add(typeof(Operator));

            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xPlugins), type.ToArray());

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open);

            plugins = (xPlugins)xml.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Using:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        readXML.getObject(ref this.plugins);

        foreach (xPlugin plugin in plugins.Plugin)
        {
            plugin.calculator.Calculate();
        }
    }
```

Deserialize process success to deserialize `xPlugins` and `xPlugin` into its associate class, but fail to deserialize `add`, `multiple`, `divide`, `divide` into its base class `Calculator`. `xPlugin`'s `calculator` property always get null value. So how can I can deserialize those elements to its base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xPlugins>
  <xPlugin>
    <Multiple>
      <Operators>
        <Add>
          <Operators>
            <Operator>
              <value>1</value>
            </Operator>
            <Operator>
              <value>2</value>
            </Operator>
           </Operators>
        </Add>        
        <Add>
          <Operators>
            <Operator>
              <value>3</value>
            </Operator>
            <Operator>
              <value>4</value>
            </Operator>
            </Operators>
        </Add>
      </Operators>
    </Multiple>
  </xPlugin>
</xPlugins>
```

This should work:

```
public abstract class Calculator
{
    public Calculator() { }

    public virtual int Calculate()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Operator : Calculator
{
    public int value { get; set; }

    public Operator() { }

    public Operator(string name)
    {
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class Add : Calculator
{
    [XmlArray("Operators")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Add", typeof(Add))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Minus", typeof(Minus))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Multiple", typeof(Multiple))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Operator", typeof(Operator))]
    public List<Calculator> calculators { get; set; }

    public Add() { }

    public Add(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {         
        List<int> value = new List<int>();

        foreach (Calculator calculator in calculators)
        {
            value.Add(calculator.Calculate());
        }

        return value.Sum();
    }
}

public class Minus : Calculator
{
    [XmlArray("Operators")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Add", typeof(Add))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Minus", typeof(Minus))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Multiple", typeof(Multiple))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Operator", typeof(Operator))]
    public List<Calculator> calculators { get; set; }

    public Minus() { }

    public Minus(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        int value = calculators[0].Calculate();

        for (int i = 1; i < calculators.Count; i++)
        {
            value -= calculators[i].Calculate();
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public class Divide : Calculator
{
    [XmlArray("Operators")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Add", typeof(Add))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Minus", typeof(Minus))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Multiple", typeof(Multiple))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Operator", typeof(Operator))]
    public List<Calculator> calculators { get; set; }

    public Divide() { }

    public Divide(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        int value = calculators[0].Calculate();

        for (int i = 1; i < calculators.Count; i++)
        {
            value /= calculators[i].Calculate();
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public class Multiple : Calculator
{
    [XmlArray("Operators")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Add", typeof(Add))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Minus", typeof(Minus))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Multiple", typeof(Multiple))]
    [XmlArrayItem("Operator", typeof(Operator))]
    public List<Calculator> calculators { get; set; }

    public Multiple() { }

    public Multiple(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        int value = calculators[0].Calculate();

        for (int i = 1; i < calculators.Count; i++)
        {
            value *= calculators[i].Calculate();
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public class xPlugin
{
    [XmlElement("Add", typeof(Add))]
    [XmlElement("Minus", typeof(Minus))]
    [XmlElement("Multiple", typeof(Multiple))]
    [XmlElement("Operator", typeof(Operator))]
    public Calculator calculator { get; set; }
}

public class xPlugins
{
    [XmlElement("xPlugin", typeof(xPlugin))]
    public xPlugin[] Plugin { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Still got null value, Sir!

Comment: I got an exception like this: http://i244.photobucket.com/albums/gg20/trongcuong1710/error-1.png. Don't know what's the cause of the problem

Comment: It works for me, are you sure you are not duplicating an XmlArrayItem.I have got the same error when I do:
[XmlArrayItem("Multiple", typeof(Multiple))]
[XmlArrayItem("Multiple", typeof(Divide))]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had solved my problem. Here is my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292634/deserialize-xml-into-super-class-object-with-c-sharp