# VB.net - How can i call the class by string name?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to store the class name in database  as string

Then i want to call this class and it's sub by string

How can to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke member through reflection passing derived class as argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380302/invoke-member-through-reflection-passing-derived-class-as-argument)

Comment: You cant "call" a class at all - it is just a blueprint for the *objects* or instances created from it.  For storage, depending on what it contains, you can serialize it and save the result.