# Is there a way to define an implicit conversion operator in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

In C#, you can use the [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28VS.80%29.aspx) keyword to define an implicit user-defined type conversion operator.

In VB.NET, you can define a [CType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4x2877xb.aspx) conversion operator that will explicitly convert a user-defined type into another type.

Is there a way to declare an implicit conversion operator in VB.NET?

I can't seem to find any information on this....

---

#### Answer

I found my answer in the MSDN documentation for the [`Widening`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312549/is-there-a-way-to-define-an-implicit-conversion-operator-in-vb-net/1312595#1312595) operator. Apparently the CType `Widening` operator is "called" for implicit conversions whereas the CType [`Narrowing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/4w127ed2%28VS.80%29.aspx) operator is called for explicit conversions.

At first, I thought this documentation was incorrect, because I was experiencing an exception during testing. I re-tested and found something very strange. The function I implemented as the widening conversion operator works fine when an implicit cast is done using the "=" operator.

For example, the following will implicitly cast the `Something` type into `MyClass`. It calls my `Widening` conversion implementation correctly and everything works without error:

```
Dim y As Something
Dim x As MyClass = y
```

However, if the implicit cast is done in a `foreach` loop, it does not work.

For example, the following code will throw an exception ("*Unable to cast object of type 'Something' to type 'MyClass'*") when the `Something` type is implicitly casted to `MyClass` in the `For Each` loop:

```
 Dim anArrayOfSomethingTypes() As Something  = getArrayOfSomethings()
 For Each x As MyType In anArrayOfSomethingTypes 
  ....
 Next
```

Any insight on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In VB.NET, use the Widening CType operator to create an implicit conversion:

```
Class C1
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal p1 As C1) As C2

    End Operator
End Class
```

The opposite, an explicit conversion, can be done by swapping `Narrowing` for `Widening` in the above definition.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the difference between Widening and Narrowing. I've already implemented a Widening Operator and a Narrowing Operator. The Widening Operator accepts a parameter of SomeType and converts it into an instance of MyObject. The narrowing operator takes a parameter of MyObject and converts it to SomeType. I guess my question really is "Is my user-defined CType operator automatically used when Explicit Casting occurs between these two types?"

Comment: ERR!! I meant Implicit.  My question really is "Is my user-defined CType operator automatically used when IMPLICIT Casting occurs between these two types?" (Big Ooops)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.
I think I skipped over your fist sentence or something. The Widening Operator called for implicit conversions. I found my answer hehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312549/is-there-a-way-to-define-an-implicit-conversion-operator-in-vb-net/1312595#1312595re:

Comment: I just tried it, and I got an error: Unable to cast object of type 'OtherNamespace.Something' to type 'MyNamespace.MyClass'.

Comment: Apparently, the Widening CType implementation is not automtically called during implicit casting.

Comment: I do not see the error when I use the CType method to cast the Something to MyClass (which uses the Widening CType implementation)

Comment: Aha! It does work if the implicit cast is done using the "=". For example: Dim x As MyClass = y (where y is an 'OtherNamespace.Something'). However if the implicit cast is done in a foreach loop it does not work. For for example For Each x As MyType in anArrayOfSomethingTypes ....

Comment: Please see my updated question. I don't understand why I'm seeing this strange behaviour.