# Override/Handle My Own Type Conversions In .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to define an implicit conversion operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312549/is-there-a-way-to-define-an-implicit-conversion-operator-in-vb-net)

I can't remember ever seeing or hearing of anyone do this; but now I'm in a situation where I think it would be incredibly useful to define my own custom 'type conversion' for my class.

As an example - let's say I have my own class, 'AwesomeDataManager'.  It does not inherit from DataTable, but it holds data in a similar fashion to a DataTable.  I would to be able to say, 'myDataTable = CType(MyAwesomeDataManager, DataTable)' and have it execute some code inside my class that would return a populated DataTable.

Granted, I could do something like 'MyAwesomeDataManager.GetDataTable' but for the sake of integrating with an existing code base, I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Doh - yes, I believe this is a duplicate.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an implicit or explicit cast, like this: (Note that LetMeChange is implicitly cast to SomethingMoreComfortable)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LetMeChange original = new LetMeChange { Name = "Bob" };
        SomethingMoreComfortable casted = original;

        Console.WriteLine(casted.Name);
    }
}

public class LetMeChange
{
    public static implicit operator SomethingMoreComfortable(LetMeChange original)
    {
        return new SomethingMoreComfortable() { Name = original.Name };
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class SomethingMoreComfortable
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two keywords in C# that help with type conversions: `implicit` and `explicit`.

In this case, you would want `implicit` for code eye-candy.  Be careful with this however, as it can cause moments of confusion as people realise what you are doing.  I tend to not spot the use of implicit conversions just by reading the code quickly (explicit are hard to miss as they need casts).