# Can a property return a default value (similar to some built-in .NET properties)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop, properties

Is there a way to have a class that can return a default type without specifying the property?

If I had a class that had a few properties and one property returned a string value and others returned additional types, could I do the following?

```
Dim StudentGrade as new StudentGradeClass
```

Call and get default property,

```
Dim CurrentGrade as string=StudentGrade
```

instead of this

```
Dim CurrentGrade as string=StudentGrade.Current
```

The reason I am asking this is when I have classes that have other classes as properties and would like to just get a default return value.

Comment: Out of interest, what are the built-in properties that you think exhibit this behaviour?

Comment: There are *no* “built in .NET properties” that behave like that. But, as some answers explain, you can achieve this via implicit conversions – but beware of those.

Comment: I was referring to the DateTime.now Property.  It's a class in of itslef, but can return a date type that will convert to a string

Comment: DateTime.Now is a static (Shared in VB) property of DateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An implicit conversion operator (Widening conversion operator in VB) will get you basically what you want, but this is really a hindrance to readability. I would advise you not to do it unless you have a really, really, really good reason.

**References:**

- *[How to: Define a Conversion Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yf7b9sy7.aspx)*
- *[Is there a way to define an implicit conversion operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312549/is-there-a-way-to-define-an-implicit-conversion-operator-in-vb-net)*

Comment: I agree, `StudentGrade.Current` is more expressive and readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET framework has no support for what you refer to as a "default property." You could potentially fake it through the use of [implicit operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but I would suggest that it is probably a bad idea to do so.

Comment: Is this what the DateTime.Now property does?

Comment: No, DateTime.Now is just a static property on the DateTime class. Same thing your example does. To fit what your asking, it would be as if DateTime itself would be the current date / time.

Comment: @jdross: No. `DateTime.Now` is a `static` property (so you wouldn't say `new DateTime().Now`), and it just creates and returns a new `DateTime` instance whenever it is called. What you're asking to do would be more like trying to cast a `DateTime` instance as a `long`. That's where implicit operators could help you, but there is a reason that the creators of the .NET framework didn't make `DateTime`s implicitly convertible to `long`. It would just introduce unnecessary confusion. It's better to provide a `Ticks` property so users know exactly what the `long` represents.