# CSharp/DotNet: Serialization, Generics and base classes

Tags: .net, generics, serialization, inheritance

Can someone tell me why this class requires `[XmlInclude(typeof(AutoHedgerBaseDataObject))]` to deserialize properly?  It's not clear to me.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(AutoHedgerBaseDataObject))]
public abstract class AutoHedgerCommandMessage 
{
    #region Variables

    private string myUpdatedBy;
    private string myUpdatedTime;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public AutoHedgerCommandMessage(string name)           
    {
        myUpdatedBy = Environment.UserName;
        myUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("YYYYMMdd HH:mm:ss zzz");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [XmlElement("updated_by")]
    public string UpdatedBy
    {
        get { return myUpdatedBy; }
        set { myUpdatedBy = value; }
    }


    [XmlElement("updated_time")]
    public string UpdatedTime
    {
        get { return myUpdatedTime; }
        set { myUpdatedTime = value; }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Methods

    protected T[] ToArrayOfType<T>(IList<string> ids, string source)
        where T : AutoHedgerBaseDataObject, new()
    {
        T[] list = new T[] { };
        if (ids != null)
        {
            list = new T[ids.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
            {
                list[i] = new T();
                list[i].Id = ids[i];
                list[i].Source = source;
            }

        }
        return list;
    }       

    #endregion
}
```

Although we have several classes that inherit from this base class, only one of them fails to serialize without the `XmlInclude` and that is a class that has no serializable properties or data and does not call any methods on the base class. This is the class that fails to deserialize:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "command")]
public class GetAutoHedgerHedgesCommand : AutoHedgerCommandMessage
{
    #region Constructors

    // Parameterless constructor for serialization/deserialization
    public GetAutoHedgerHedgesCommand()
        : base(Name)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constants

    public const string Name = "get_autohedger_hedges";

    #endregion        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because something in the base class or the derived class is causing a list of items to be serialised that you didnt explicitly mention in your interface (this class itself doesnt expose anything that would direcly lead to the issue).

[This has been covered pretty completely in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084/xml-serialization-and-inherited-types)