# Serialization across projects with inheritance

Tags: c#, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a base class ("MyBaseClass") in  a project called "BaseFramework" which is included in several solutions within the company. There are several derived class's in various projects throughout the company that inherit from "MyBaseClass". If I then create a List and add derived class's to it, it will not serialize. I realise that if I were attempting to serialize this list, and the base class and derived class were in the same project, I could simply apply the "XmlInclude" attribute to the base class and include all of the derived class's. This is however not possible across projects, because that would require a circular dependency.
Is this possible to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Serialization and Inherited Types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084/xml-serialization-and-inherited-types)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at sending stuff over network, then you should definitelly look into .Net XML Web Services.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12PGpwy8SUY

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996507.aspx