# Unable to Serialize array Object in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I have the following class:

```
public partial class ct_ServiceProductInfoWireless {

    private object[] itemsField;
    private bool directFulfillmentField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("NewWirelessLines", typeof(ct_WirelessLines))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WirelessLine", typeof(ct_ServiceProductInfoWirelessWirelessLine))]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**ct_WirelessLines Class**

```
public partial class ct_WirelessLines {

    private ct_NewWirelessLine[] wirelessLineField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WirelessLine")]
    public ct_NewWirelessLine[] WirelessLine {
        get {
            return this.wirelessLineField;
        }
        set {
            this.wirelessLineField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I serialize my ct_ServiceProductInfoWireless Object I get following Exception:

> The type ct_WirelessLines[] may not be used in this context.

This is the serialization code:

```
var stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, objectToSerialize); //Getting exception here
return stringWriter.ToString();
```

What is wrong?

**ct_NewWirelessLine class**

```
public partial class ct_NewWirelessLine {

    private ct_NewRatePlan ratePlanField;

    private ct_DataPlan dataPlanField;

    private ct_OrderDevice deviceField;

    private ct_PhoneNumber telephoneNumberField;

    private string lineNumberField;

    private bool isPrimaryLineField;
}
```

**ct_ServiceProductInfoWirelessWirelessLine class**

```
public partial class ct_ServiceProductInfoWirelessWirelessLine {

    private ct_Device deviceField;

    private ct_RatePlan ratePlanField;

    private ct_InstallmentPlan installmentPlanField;

    private string paymentArrangementField;

    private ct_OptionalFeature[] optionalPackagesField;

    private ct_WirelessFeature[] optionalFeaturesField;

    private string lineNumberField;

    private string primarySQNumberField;

    private string secondarySQNumberField;

    private st_CustomerType customerTypeField;

    private bool customerTypeFieldSpecified;

    private string ppuZipField;

    private string wtnField;

    private bool directFulfillmentField;

    private bool directFulfillmentFieldSpecified;
}
```

Comment: Please publish `ct_ServiceProductInfoWirelessWirelessLine` and `ct_NewWirelessLine` classes, because when i created those custom classes it worked well, thus the problem is probably in those classes definitions.

Comment: I am unable to pinpoint where exactly the issue is, in your code. Yet, found the below article with a similar question and some answers. Hope it will help you get a clue for a workaround.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897818/xmlserializer-the-type-type-may-not-be-used-in-this-context?rq=1

Comment: You have a big amount of classes, start by comments out many properties until you find the problematic class definition.

Comment: Private properties do not get serialized.

Comment: I was able to get the error message `System.InvalidOperationException: The type ct_WirelessLines[] may not be used in this context.` by assigning `ct_ServiceProductInfoWireless.Items` to be an array of array of `ct_WirelessLines` instead of a 1d array:  `Items = new [] { new [] { new ct_WirelessLines() } }`.  Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PaXdUR.  The code compiles because `Items` is just an array of objects, but won't serialize because `XmlSerializer` expects only the objects of the two declared types in the array, and not some nested array.  Could you be doing that?

Comment: @dbc You're right! Its an array of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error message

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: The type ct_WirelessLines[] may not be used in this context.
> ```

by assigning `ct_ServiceProductInfoWireless.Items` to be an **array of array of `ct_WirelessLines`** instead of a 1-dimensional array:

```
Items = new [] { new [] { new ct_WirelessLines() } }`
```

This code compiles because `Items` is just an array of objects, but won't serialize because `XmlSerializer` expects only objects of the two types declared in [`XmlElementAttribute.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.type) attributes to be in the array, and not some nested array.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PaXdUR).

The solution would be to not do that and use a flat 1d array:

```
Items = new [] { new ct_WirelessLines() },
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rky60e).

If you have two collections, one of `ct_WirelessLines` and one of `ct_ServiceProductInfoWirelessWirelessLine`, you can combine them into the final `Items` array by using upcasting the collection contents to `object`, then using [`Concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat) and [`ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray):

```
var wirelessLines = GetWirelessLines(); // Some IEnumerable<ct_WirelessLines>
var productInfo = GetProductInfoWirelessWirelessLines(); // Some IEnumerable<ct_ServiceProductInfoWirelessWirelessLine>

var objectToSerialize = new ct_ServiceProductInfoWireless
{
    Items = wirelessLines.Cast<object>().Concat(productInfo).ToArray(),
};
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OAoVGR).

**As an aside**, it looks as though this code was auto-generated by [`xsd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe).  This tool generally will not automatically generate a class hierarchy for sequences of choice elements.  However, if you can manually modify the generated code, you could introduce an abstract base class for your `Items` which will prevent the sort of error you encountered at compile time:

```
public partial class ct_ServiceProductInfoWireless 
{
    private WirelessItemBase[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("NewWirelessLines", typeof(ct_WirelessLines))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WirelessLine", typeof(ct_ServiceProductInfoWirelessWirelessLine))]
    public WirelessItemBase[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class WirelessItemBase
{
}

public partial class ct_WirelessLines : WirelessItemBase
{
}

public partial class ct_ServiceProductInfoWirelessWirelessLine : WirelessItemBase
{
}
```

Now the following won't even compile:

```
Items = new [] { new [] { new ct_WirelessLines() } }, //Compilation error (line 72, col 13): Cannot implicitly convert type 'ct_WirelessLines[][]' to 'WirelessItemBase[]'
```

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BBS9sD).