# Deserializing an object from XML in C# with derived classes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a very simple XML file below:

```
<Job Name="test">
    <Pages>
        <MainPage Name="page1"/>
    </Pages>
</Job>
```

'MainPage' is a derived class of PageBase, with my class structure as below

```
public class Job
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public List<PageBase> Pages { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(MainPage))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SubPage))]
public abstract class PageBase
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}

public class MainPage : PageBase
{

}

public class SubPage : PageBase
{

}
```

And here is the sample code I use to deserialize:

```
var xml = "<Job Name=\"test\"><Pages><MainPage Name=\"page1\"></MainPage></Pages></Job>";
MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(str);
writer.Write(xml);
writer.Flush();
str.Position = 0;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Job));
var job = (Job)serializer.Deserialize(str);
```

However, I get the below error - despite including my XmlInclude's on the PageBase type. What am I doing wrong? DotNetFiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UucVmX

> Run-time exception (line 18): There is an error in XML document (1,
>   19).
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type is abstract:
>   name='PageBase', namespace='', at .]    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderJob.Read4_PageBase(Boolean
>   isNullable, Boolean checkType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderJob.Read5_Job(Boolean
>   isNullable, Boolean checkType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderJob.Read6_Job()
>
> [System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
>   (1, 19).]    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)
>   at Program.Main() :line 18

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML Serialization and Inherited Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084/xml-serialization-and-inherited-types) This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737666/xml-serialization-problem-deserializing-an-abstract-property) will also be helpful

Comment: Unfortunately not, as I already have XmlInclude's but they aren't working

Comment: You should implement `IXmlSerializable` for the abstract type, like it's explained in mentioned threads

Comment: Isn't the point of XmlInclude to make this scenario 'just work' though, without having to implement this interface?

Comment: Create some test data in your classes and then serialize to see the xml output and what you code produces.  The include requires type attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML to:

```
<Job Name="test">
    <Pages>
        <PageBase xsi:type="MainPage" Name="page1"/>
    </Pages>
</Job>
```

Try to serialize your object first and check the XML it produces. You should see that the XML-Element will be PageBase and xsi:type="MainPage".