# How to serialize abstract classes with a large number of subclasses?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize a class with a field containing another class, but the field name appears in the XML.

I have the following classes:

```cs
public class CustomExpression
{
    [XmlAttribute] public string callFormat;
    [XmlAttribute] public string format;
    [XmlAttribute] public string name;
    [XmlAttribute] public string style;

    public VzExpression child;

    
    /* constructor and methods */
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(BinaryOp)) /* other subclasses */]
public abstract class VzExpression {}

public class BinaryOp : VzExpression
{
    public VzExpression left;
    public VzExpression right;    

    /* constructor and methods */
}

/* And some more subclasses */
```

Which currently serializes as:

```xml
<CustomExpression callFormat="" format="" name="" style="">
  <child xsi:type="BinaryOp" ...>
    <left ... />
    <right ... />
  </child>
</CustomExpression>
```

What I instead want is (replace VzExpression with concrete type):

```xml
<CustomExpression callFormat="" format="" name="" style="">
  <BinaryOp ...>
    <VzExpression ... />
    <VzExpression ... />
  </BinaryOp>
</CustomExpression>
```

How should I achieve this?

One solution I attempted, as suggested by @dbc, was adding the `[XmlElement("BinaryOp", typeof(BinaryOp))]` attribute to the field for every subclass. However, the number of subclasses is large (~ 10). Is there a way to do this without having to apply 10 attributes every time I use VzExpression?

Comment: Instead of `[XmlInclude(typeof(BinaryOp))` apply [`[XmlElement(typeof(BinaryOp))]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-xml-serialization-xmlelementattribute-ctor(system-type)) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643424/3744182) by Marc Gravell to [Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643139/3744182).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: And also [XML Serialization: Problem deserializing an abstract property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6738045).  Do those answer your question?

Comment: Yes, applying `[XmlElement("BinaryOp", typeof(BinaryOp))` to `public VzExpression child;` works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/bfBZso.  Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @dbc, I have many such subclasses of VzExpression. Do I have to do this for every subclass, every time I use VzExpression?

Comment: There is nothing builtin to do this, to support polymorphism via element name MSFT requires you to add attributes to each property.  (Just a guess here, but it might be because there could be multiple properties of the same type in a given class.)  You could experiment with manufacturing a custom serializer with `XmlAttributeOverrides` specified, see e.g. [Serialize a list of objects inheriting from class A to xml, so the names of the elements in the xml are B,C,D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50471935/3744182).

Comment: Anyway, if adding `[XmlElement(...)]` to every property is too much of a burden, I'd suggest that you either ask a new question, or [edit] this question, and explain your requirements precisely, including why adding attributes is not sufficient.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: *What I instead want is (replace VzExpression with concrete type):* -- you can't get that with `XmlSerializer`, because you are mapping two different fields, `left` and `right`, to the same element name `<VzExpression />`.  `XmlSerializer` generally only supports schema that can be round-tripped and there is no way to deserialize such XML and correctly bind to `left` and `right`.

Comment: @dbc, I could make it into a list, retaining left and right only in the constructor. That still leaves the 10 attributes problem though.