# Can you cast down when passing a model to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Lets say I have two classes one base class:

```
public class BaseModel {

}
```

And a couple of children:

```
public class FooModel : BaseModel {

}

public class BarModel : BaseModel {

}
```

Now my view I would like to expect a model like this:

```
@model IList<BaseModel>
```

So that I can edit these models on one page.

However when I pass in a collection of these models in the action I get an exception saying:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BarModel]', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[BaseModel]'.

Like this:

```
var models = new List<BaseModel>(){ new BarModel(), new FooModel ()}
return View(models);
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: When serializing inherited classes you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084/xml-serialization-and-inherited-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not modify the model collection on the page, your page shouldn't take `IList<T>`. Rather it should take `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
@model IEnumerable<BaseModel>
```

That should take care of things.

Comment: *facepalm*, can't believe. But why doesn't it work with the IList?

Comment: @shenku - Start here. There are 11 parts to the series. Obviously, it's a bit complicated to explain: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Comment: just a quick question, this works perfectly, for a post back though to the base type, is there a way i can then cast or try cast to an implementation type?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can alseo use KnownType:

```
[Serilizable]
[KnownType(typeof(FooModel))]
[KnownType(typeof(BarModel))]
public class BaseModel 
{
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that applies to MVC, that's for WCF and serialization.  MVC is not serializing the type.