# Possible to validate a .NET Attibute parameter?

Tags: c#, attributes

I am wondering if it is possible to validate parameters to (custom) .net attributes.  eg: If I had an attribute that takes a positive integer, could I force a compile time error when a negative value was supplied?

[DonkeyAttribute(1)] //OK

[DonkeyAttribute(-828)] //error

In this example I could use an unsigned integer (but that is non cls compliant I beleive?)
Recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is normally, however [this](http://karlagius.wordpress.com/2008/01/29/validating-attribute-usage-with-postsharp-aspects/) article details a solution using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/). Not sure if it's fit for your purpose, but give it go!

Answer (score 1):

You could enforce this with unit tests; a similar solution to the one I proposed for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454/enforce-attribute-decoration-of-classesmethods#19455), maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Directly? No. Not without rewriting csc or vbc. Most people would perform said validation at runtime.

However, a bit of Googling came up with this [blog entry on PostSharp Aspects](http://karlagius.wordpress.com/2008/01/29/validating-attribute-usage-with-postsharp-aspects/). It doesn't technically validate from the compiler, but it does provide checking at compile-time. You can check it out [here](http://www.postsharp.org/). Other notes about PostSharp from the same author can be found [here](http://karlagius.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/aop-using-postsharp-laos/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute by inheriting from System.Attribute. In the custom Constructor you should be able to check the parameters.